# is there any other way instead of SVN to combine and worked together on a iPhone project from different pc

Tags: iphone, svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to work in a big project. Now i have many other friends that are working with me together. but i am going to try that implementation with the SVN. but i was not able to implement it properly.
Is there any other way or tools that allow to attched the project and work together simultaneously. ?
Please help me regarding this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean *"was not able to implement it properly"*? You couldn't get it to work, or you didn't have the resources (like a machine that could be dedicated as a server).

Subversion is one of the easiest version control systems to get up and running. You create a repository via the `svnadmin create` command, then you have a whole slew of different ways to implement it: Over httpd Apache, over its own internal svnserver, or over SSH. There are public Subversion servers out there you can use for free too.

If you give us a bit more information what went wrong, we can give you some advice. If you're not familiar with version control, you may be confusing the server with the client. Or, you might have forgotten a minor step in getting Subversion up and running (such as starting svnserve, or enabling the password line in your `svnserve.conf` file). Just let us know, and we can help.

By the way, I agree GIT is an excellent choice. With GIT, you can share work without needing a centralized server up and running at all times. I've successfully kept projects with GIT using [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com). Heck, you can even synchronize your work with GIT via email if you'd like. But, if you're having problems with Subversion, you'll probably have even more issues getting GIT up and running.

Comment: I have use git. but it gets crash while more than one users working on same project.. So Is there any other Software that can help me out. . .?  or any other solution that can solve that problem. I don't have server for my own. Thanks for the Reply.

Comment: Will you please give me the link for the public Subversion servers ??

Comment: And let me try again with SVN. If i will get any error i will inform you. Thanks for the support and if possible then give me the link for the public Subversion Servers that use as free. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice details.

Answer (score 0):

If your are several to work on the same XCode project the better advice you could get is to use git. Git is a lot better than SVN to work simultaneously on the same project because its the central idea of it's conception; Take a look at git documentation and how it's easy to handle merge situations.
My good references:
[Modernize Your Git Workflow](http://object.io/site/2011/enter-git-flow/)
[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: I have tried it with git. but it seems like a some what bad experiance. So is there any other way to do it instead of git and SVN ?? Thanks for your reply. .

Comment: Source control software are far the best way to do what you want

Comment: Hey, Will you please give me Some details or links regarding this Source Control Software. . ? May be it can help me a lot.

Comment: I want links for that Source control Software. . .

Comment: Thanks for the links. but i want the link of that Source Control Software that you have mention above.

Comment: Checkout Wikipedia... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software